# Is it possible to suppress the IE standard login dialog when Windows Authentication is enabled?

Tags: web-config

i have a web application with Windows Authentication enabled. In my web.config I restrict the access with the following code:

```
 <authorization>
  <allow users="rba\eigg"/>
  <deny users="*"/>
 </authorization>
```

When I call the application in a browser, the IE's standard login dialog pops up. If I close it by 'Cancel' I get the HTTP 401 (Access is denied) error page as  expected.

Is there a way to suppress the login dialog so that the user gets the 401 error page directly?

Thanks!
Rocko

Answer (score 0):

At risk of sounding terse, let me just say: **No**. ;-)

It is an intrisic function of any browser when presented with a challenge/response type of auth.

Fiddling with this in any way would be a security risk and is not possible.

Just the way it is.

Cheers.